# Outside-In 2D array algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math

I was given a series of non-negative integers.

```
43 18 5 67 1 72 16 17 15 93 38 6 83 10 49 98 7 47 61 52 71 79 82 52 8
```

I need to store it in **m * n** array from the **Outside-In**. As follows:

```
m = 5
n = 5
```

[image: outside-in]

Then, I need to calculate the sum of certain part of the 2D array. *(I have done this part already)*.

My ideal approach to store the numbers:

```
 1. Initialize starti,startj = 0.
 2. Initialize endi = m , endj = n.
 3. Store the remaining numbers in array[starti][j], where j starts from startj and ends at endj.
 4. Store the remaining numbers in array[i][endj], where i starts from starti and ends at endi.
 5. Store the remaining numbers in array[endi][j], where j starts from endj and ends at startj.
 6. Store the remaining numbers in array[i][endj], where i starts from endi and ends at starti.
 7. Decrement endi and endj by 1. 
 8. Increment starti and start j by 1.
 9. Repeat the steps 3 - 8 until the last number is stored.
```

**Question :** Is there any better way to solve this problem ?

**Additional:** I have been trying come up *(but failed)* with a `formula to find where the last element is stored before doing all these operation.`

Comment: Have you implemented your method? Does this produce correct output but you are looking for a better method? Or this does not produce correct output?

Comment: I didn't implement  these methods yet but I believe it will produce the right output.

Comment: You should implement a crawler instead of a formula to find out where the number #N should go in an array of W*H dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way.

First you can start out thinking recursively

Have a method which has a signature like `fill(m,n,starting_position, direction)

The recursive version will look something like

```
fill(m,n, starting_position, direction) {

// If m=0 or n=0 you have a base case.
// Start at starting position, and fill in the direction.
// Decrement m or n, depending on the direction
// Compute new starting position and direction
// Recursively call fill with the updated m,n, starting_pos, direction
}
```

Now notice that this method is tail-recursive, and so you can get rid of the recursion and replace it with a while loop, with the condition of the while loop derived from the base case.

Comment: It wasn't my homework. This is a practice problem for local ACM-ICPC practice problem in my country.